Unity using LineRenderer to draw lines on a sphere
I am trying to draw lines on a globe like the scientific software app GPlates. In GPlates you draw polygons on a globe by clicking on the globe to place vertices.
I asked ChatGPT for help, it provided the first two methods. I wrote the last one. Because I was already working with texture UV coordinates I tried using those. This is really a shot in the dark. I don't know what vectors I should slerp. to get LinerRenderer to draw the lines I want.
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MousePosition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float radius = 1.0f; // The radius of your sphere
    //public Vector2[] geoCoordinates; // Array of (latitude, longitude) points
    public int numSegments = 100; // Number of segments for smoothness

    private Vector3 prevHit;
    
    void DrawCurvedLineOnSphere(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint)
    {
        List<Vector3> linePoints = new List<Vector3>();

            // Interpolate along the great circle path using Slerp
            for (int j = 0; j <= numSegments; j++)
            {
                float t = (float)j / (float)numSegments;
                Vector3 interpolatedPoint = Vector3.Slerp(startPoint, endPoint, t);
                linePoints.Add(interpolatedPoint);
            }

        // Set the LineRenderer points
        lineRenderer.positionCount = linePoints.Count;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(linePoints.ToArray());
    }

    Vector3 ConvertGeoToCartesian(float latitude, float longitude, float radius)
    {
        // Convert degrees to radians
        float latRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * latitude;
        float lonRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * longitude;

        // Calculate Cartesian coordinates
        float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(latRad) * Mathf.Cos(lonRad);
        float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(latRad);
        float z = radius * Mathf.Cos(latRad) * Mathf.Sin(lonRad);

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
    
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                Renderer renderer = hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                Material mat = renderer.material;
                Texture2D texture2D = mat.mainTexture as Texture2D;

                // Convert hit texture coordinates to pixel coordinates
                Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
                pixelUV.x *= texture2D.width;
                pixelUV.y *= texture2D.height;
                Debug.Log("x: " + pixelUV.x + " y: " + pixelUV.y);

                // Check if texture is readable before modifying pixels
                if (texture2D.isReadable) {
                    // Set pixel color
                    texture2D.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.red);

                    // Apply pixel changes
                    texture2D.Apply();

                    // Log success
                    Debug.Log("Pixel color set successfully!");
                } else {
                    Debug.LogError("Texture is not readable. Adjust import settings.");
                }
                
                if (prevHit != null) {
                    DrawCurvedLineOnSphere(prevHit, ConvertGeoToCartesian(pixelUV.x, pixelUV.y, radius));
                }
                prevHit = ConvertGeoToCartesian(pixelUV.x, pixelUV.y, radius);
            }
        }
    }
}

I placed a sphere that I made in blender at the world origin. The scale is 100 for x, y, and z. I believe radius 1.0 is appropriate for that?
Currently this will create a single line that goes off into infinity while intersecting the sphere and it only draws a line while holding down the mouse button and dragging. This is when using Alignment: Transform Z in my LineRenderer. My goal is to draw a line with just 2 clicks.
Chat GPT wants to use UV coordinates and convert those to 3d Cartesian coordinates. This makes sense as eventually I will probably want to store information in longitude/latitude coordinates, not world space. Overall I am pretty confused about what coordinates I need.
My raycast also seems to be landing on the opposite side of the sphere, I'm not sure what's  causing that. I successfully set the pixel color but on the other side of the sphere.
The closest I have found to answering my question is this How to draw latitude/longitude lines on the surface of a Sphere in Unity 3D? but it is light on code and not exactly what I want to do.

There are generally 2 big coordinate systems: GCS (aka long, lat, height), ECEF (earth-centered, earth-fixed) and then a variety of subsystems based on ECEF ... Basically you need to convert from the geodetic to ECEF system and then scale it down .. and then convert that to Unity left-handed Z-up coordinate space

Though seems I mixed up the questions a bit .. this one is only about how to draw lines on a sphere not about translating between the coordinate systems
